# Penalty Function for XOR gate

Tags: mathematics, adiabatic-model

I was reading a paper on [Gates for Adiabatic Quantum Computer](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1405/1405.2354.pdf). In the paper, there were different penalty functions already given in the form of the following table:
[image]

I do not quite understand the process for getting the penalty functions, in which the penalty functions contain extra variables (like XOR Gate). Can anyone please explain the Math behind this? I have tried to find some resources, but I was not able to get any good ones. It will be of great help if anyone can explain how these penalty functions are derived, or even a good resource will do fine.

Comment: Hi @Srijan.  I don't understand the purpose of this table.  For example, the implication $x_i \rightarrow x_j$ in the fifth row.  I don't understand why $x_a$ is necessary.  Why not just use the penalty function $(x_i-x_j)x_i$?  It accomplishes the same thing.  What do I not understand about this table?