# Is there a compendium of quadratic penalties for logic relationships between binary variables?

Tags: qubo

I'm looking for a compendium/look-up table for a relationship between binary variables, and corresponding QUBO penalty functions.  I'm aware of a few from DWave docs, [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18265/penalty-function-for-xor-gate), but I can't find a comprehensive single resource.  Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

| logic | penalty |
| --- | --- |
| $x_i \rightarrow x_j$ | $(x_i -x_j)x_i$ |
| $\bar{x_i} \rightarrow x_j$ | $1-x_i x_j - x_i -x_j$ |
| $\bar{x_i} \rightarrow \bar{x_j}$ | $ x_j - x_j x_i $ |

Such a table would be tremendously helpful for other logical relationships involving other logical relationship, etc.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?